# Jquery to change the display style into display=block of div element based on combobox?

Tags: jquery, combobox

I set the `.show` div style to `display: none;` on CSS so it hidden, but I want it to `display: block` when the user choose others of my combobox in my form.
how can make it show using Jquery?

```css
.show{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="list.php" method="post">
  <select id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="other">others</option>
  </select>
    <div class="show">
    <label for="specify">Specify*</label>
    <input type="text" name="specify">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#select" ).change(function() {
    if ($("#select").val() == "other") {
      $(".specify_text").removeClass("show");
    } else {
      $(".specify_text").addClass("show");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.show{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="list.php" method="post">
  <select id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="other">others</option>
  </select>
  <div class="specify_text show">
    <label for="specify">Specify*</label>
    <input type="text" name="specify">
  </div>
</form>
```

Try this one...

Comment: can I put that jquery code inside my header? sorry i'm new to javascript

Comment: Yes, you can add or you can make a new js file and include it in your HTML page.